# SQL объединение таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть три таблицы.

Главная

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И две таблицы в данными о номере недели и номере пары

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать вот так, но у меня не выходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице РАСПИСАНИЕ не все пары есть, то есть может не бы например пары 5. Но в результате должно быть не её месте NULL, точнее на месте предмета.

```
SELECT * FROM Расписание
  FULL JOIN Пары p ON Расписание.НомерПары = p.Номер
  FULL JOIN Недели w ON Расписание.НомерНедели = w.Номер
```

Comment: А как вы пробуете и что получается? И добавьте пожалуйста тегом название Вашей БД

Comment: @lDrakonl пробовал  FULL JOIN, но не выходят пустые строки. #Расписание

Comment: добавьте Ваш запрос к вопросу

Comment: @lDrakonl Добавил

Comment: А почему `full`, если вы пишите про `left join` ?

Comment: @lDrakonl "@lDrakonl пробовал FULL JOIN, но не выходят пустые строки"

Comment: Скажите все же, какая у Вас СУБД ?

Comment: @lDrakonl Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: У вас в результате есть строка с номером недели 1 и номером пары 3. А в расписании такой строки нет. Так и должно быть?

Comment: @ lDrakonl, да так должно быть. Если её нету в расписании то пишется NULL в колонке предмет. А номер недели и пара остается соответственно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select w."Номер" as "НомерНедели",
       p."Номер" as "НомерПары",
       r."Предмет" 
from   "Недели" w
cross  join "Пары" p
left  join "Расписание" r
on    w."Номер" = r."НомерНедели"
and   p."Номер" = r."НомерПары"
```